# Old urls match new urls of site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

guys i have one old site which is in joomla (that is not important). The site has unfriendly urls with too munch get parameters. Example of the urls:

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1088&Itemid=245

So we will rebuild this site on custom our platform. The site have too munch urls in forums and so on.

So basicaly we want when you got from the old urls on the site to be redirected to the new post or whatever it is.

**Solution what i have think that it will work.**

Every article/post have a old url field in the database and you match the new address with the old address.

You have a panel in the admin area *Generate htaccess* and when you generate htaccess from the admin it get the old htaccess get all matched urls (old/new) and recreate it.

The think is that i have never do this and i don't know what problems could have the system after this.

Anyone who faced this kind of challenge?

Comment: This is not a PHP question.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Apache mod_rewrite.  I suspect superuser is a better place to ask about setting that up.

Comment: @GodonM superuser? Can you tell me more?

Comment: He's referring to superuser stackexchange => http://superuser.com/

Comment: @GodonM  hum maybe you are right but it has related to the php site also.

Comment: @Christian Kiewiet I have approve your edit but i think that you are wrong the php will generate the htaccess so i think i should add php tag.

Comment: You do not have an explicitely PHP related question (yet), once you do you should consider adding a follow-up question.

Comment: A .htaccess with potentially hundreds or thousands of rules in it is a bad idea. Your question is vague - and I find it impossible to suggest a better alternative based on your description. I am voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: @Samurai8 it is not brought it is a clear idea with clear method which i have described.